# Minio Deployment in Kubernetes : Console getting redirected

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I made a Minio deployment in my 2 Node Kubernetes cluster using YAML files.

I had used an NFS server for the corresponding persistent volume and pvc associated with the same.
Once the pod is running, I created a service to access the console from the browser.

But when tried the URL `"http://<host-ip-address:nodePort>"`, the same was getting redirected to the port 45893 with the message "This site cannot be reached."

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, got a solution with the help of my friend.

We created a copy of the service and changed the Port to the port to which my Minio console was getting redirected and Nodeport to some random port allowed in the firewall. This resolved the issue.

service.yaml

```
type: LoadBalancer
ports:
  - port: 9000
    nodePort: 32767
    protocol: TCP
selector:
```

service_copy.yaml

```
ports:
  - port: 45893
    nodePort: 32766
    protocol: TCP
selector:
```

```bash
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP   X.X.X.X        <none>        443/TCP           25d
minio-xxx-service       NodePort    X.X.X.X        <none>        9000:32767/TCP    3d23h
minio-xxxx-service-cp   NodePort    X.X.X.X        <none>        45893:32766/TCP   146m
```

After doing the same, I was able to access the console.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: It's working since you changes the type to LoadBalancer, you did not resolve the issue.

Comment: No no @CodeWizard.. I didn't change the type to load balancer.. Infact we don't have a Load Balancer.. You could see the both the service types are NodePort itself.. Searched long to find an answer, but couldn't find anywhere... Do you have a permanent solution for this...?

Comment: You still have an open issue with it?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by the solution I have mentioned here @CodeWizard.. But don't know whether it is the right one...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line: `MINIO_OPTS="--certs-dir /home/swaggmode/.minio/certs --console-address :9001"` to the config file located at `/etc/default/minio` should make minio console to redirect to port 9001 or any specific port you want.

Answer (score 0):

MinIO have 2 ports,`:9000` for API port and `:9001` (or random port) for console port--the dashboard. when access to the API port via browser, it will redirect to `:9001`.

> While the port 9000 is used for connecting to the API, MinIO
> automatically redirects browser access to the MinIO Console.
> *https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html*

To fix this problem, I define the MinIO ports to the same as nodePort.

**minio-depl.yaml**

```
  args:
    - server
    - /data
    - --address
    - ":30009"
    - --console-address
    - ":31009"
```

**minio-api-svc.yaml**

```
  ports:
    - name: api
      port: 30009
      nodePort: 30009
      protocol: TCP
```

**minio-console-svc.yaml**

```
  ports:
    - name: console
      port: 31009
      nodePort: 31009
      protocol: TCP
```